# VSTO / Excel make a file excel B be embedded in a file excel A, so that B inherit custom properties and validations from A

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

i have this problem to solve:

I have a "master" excel workbook, with custom validations and properties on some cells ( for example from Cell A1 to B2 you can only insert numbers etc...); furthermore i also made a custom add-in for excel, defined locally in the solution using Visual studio 2017 and VSTO (Visual studio tools for office).

What i'd like to do is: to embed in a cell of the "master" excel file, another excel file B, and i want that this file B inherit all the validations and properties from the "master" excel.

I need to embed and make it clickable so that the user's can make their own copy of the "master" excel on their machines.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just a button that when clicked makes a copy of the master?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately the simple copy doesn't make file B inherit validations of data and protections on the cells, idk why

Comment: I think you're trying to say you made a [document-level Excel customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-document-level-customizations-for-excel), that appears for that file only (or files based on the template) and is not available otherwise. Is that accurate?

Comment: It is not possible to embed another workbook in a cell. Making a copy of the worksheet preserves data validation and protection for me. But I don't think it copies a VSTO document-level customisation,

Comment: " trying to say you made a document-level Excel customization", if i understand, yes I made one using vsto. 

"that appears for that file only (or files based on the template) ": yes but the strange thing is: if i copy the "master" excel file with my customizations in a copy1 file, the copy1 doesn't have my customizations ( validations of data in a range of cells etc.. ); if I open the master excel, then I save it in another file, copy2, then i open copy2 it appears to be all working and idk why -.-

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to copy a worksheet in a workbook and remove any protection for changing the content. Use the [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-copy-method-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm174074)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which copies the sheet to another location in the current workbook or a new workbook. The following VBA code sample copies Sheet1, placing the copy after Sheet3.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets("Sheet3")
```

Use the [Unprotect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/alloweditrange-unprotect-method-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm725077)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method to remove protection from a sheet or workbook. This method has no effect if the sheet or workbook isn't protected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but actually i need to keep the protection and all the validations from the "master" to the copy. If i simply copy the "master" file in a file B, the file B doesn't have nor the protections neither the add-in.
Sorry if i haven't explained well my needs

Comment: The code posted copies a worksheet into the same workbook, not file. You can leave the protection level as is.